# Playing around with signals

Tags: c, signals

I am currently working on a project to learn about signals, basically I have a client and a server, the server gives out a pid that I must input as a parameter to the client with a string, after being launched, the client sends this string to the server and the server displays it.

What I've done so far is convert the string into binary and if the integer is a 0 I send SIGUSR1 otherwise (if it's a 1) I send SIGUSR2, that way I want to convert the binary to the string we had previously but I am wondering how I could do so.

Here is the main for the server, as you can see it displays its pid (so we can launch the client later with it) and waits for a signal. Once it catches one it calles my_sig (that you will find later in this thread).

```
int     main()
{
  int   pid;

  pid = getpid();
  printf("Server pid is: %d\n", pid);
  if (signal(SIGUSR1, my_sig) == SIG_ERR)
    {
      printf("Error.\n");
      exit(1);
    }
  if (signal(SIGUSR2, my_sig) == SIG_ERR)
    {
      printf("Error.\n");
      exit(1);
    }
  while (1);
}
```

And here is the very simple my_sig, as you can see if it receives SIGUSR1 as a signal it displays a 0, otherwise a 1.

```
void            my_sig(int param)
{
  char          *src;
  char          *dest;

  if (param == SIGUSR1)
    {
      my_printf("0");
    }
  if (param == SIGUSR2)
    {
      my_printf("1");
    }
}
```

So at the end of the day what it does is display the word given in the client in binary char by char.

How could I use that to display the string I inputted in the client?

Thanks guys, if you need any precisions please let me know.

EDIT : As much as I would love to know about other signals, sadly, I am limited to these ones for this project.

Comment: Short and only answer is: You can't. Signals are simply not capable of transmitting any more information. You have to use some other [inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) primitive to send any data.

Comment: I understand, but once I am able to get the word in its binary form, can't I simply change it to its original one? (./client pid "hello" displays in the server process : 0110100001100101011011000110110001101111)

Comment: What do you mean by "converting a string into binary"? If you look at a string in memory using a memory.dump tool you will see that it *is* in binary, it's stored in memory as binary ones and zeroes, no explicit conversion needed. For example, the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) encoding for the character `'A'` is decimal `65`, or hex `0x41`, which is binary `01000001`. Transmitting the string *as-is* will send it's binary data, and the other process can just print it like any other string.

Answer (score 1):

Signals are largely inappropriate for this task, as it is possible to lose information depending on timing.

Standard signals will lose bits and ordering.  These signals are individually named (e.g., SIGUSR1, SIGUSR2), and *do not queue*.  That is, only one instance of any given standard signal can be pending at any time.  Additionally, their order of delivery is *not guaranteed*, but in practice is often lowest to highest.  Thus, if I sent your process USR2, USR2, USR1, USR1, USR2, USR2 and got the timing just right, your process might receive a single USR1 followed by a single USR2.

Real-time signals will lose your ordering.  These signals are numbered in the range SIGRTMIN to SIGRTMAX, they do queue, and they have a defined delivery order.  Unfortunately, that order is [lowest to highest](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html#tag_02_04_02) and thus presents a similar problem as above.  (You'd receive MIN+0, MIN+0, MIN+1, MIN+1, MIN+1, MIN+1.)

(If you used [`sigaction`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sigaction.html) rather than `signal`, and if you specified SA_SIGINFO in your signal handler registration, and if the signaling application used [`sigqueue`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sigqueue.html) to send an int along with a chosen real-time signal via `sival_int`, then you could transmit ones and zeros in sequence via signals.  That's rather a tortured use case, however.)

Answer (score 0):

Using signals to transmit binary data would be both slow and inefficient. 
If you still insist on doing it, you would have to pack the bits into bytes
rather than printing "1" or "0"

Here is one way you might do it.

```
#define MAX_BYTES 64
static int current_bit=0,current_byte=0;
static char byte=0,output_bytes[MAX_BYTES];
void            my_sig(int param){
  char          *src;
  char          *dest;

  if (param == SIGUSR1)
    {
      byte &= ~(128 >> current_bit);
    }
  if (param == SIGUSR2)
    {
      byte |= (128 >> current_bit);
    }
    current_bit++;
    if(current_bit > 7){
        current_bit = 0;
        output_byte[current_byte] = byte;
        byte = 0;
        if(current_byte < (MAX_BYTES-1)){
            current_byte++;
        }

    }
}
```

That is poor code. But the idea of sending data of signals isn't a good one anyway.

Output would be in the output_byte array.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it. I understand the idea is not a very good one but I'm learning through trying out many things.

Comment: But could you explain into detail your code? I'm not sure I understand it all.

Comment: Each byte is made of of 8 bits packed from the most significant bit (worth 128) to the least significant bit (worth 1). Numbers (or character ASCII values) are represented by having the correct bits set. So 9 for example would be 1001 in binary (8 + 1). Since you are streaming bits over signals, you need to repack those bits back into bytes in order to retrieve the number or string or else you are using 8 bits to represent 1 bit. Read up on bitwise operations to understand how the packing works.

Comment: I understand, what about "byte &= ~(128 >> current_bit);" and " byte |= (128 >> current_bit);", what do the "&=" and "|=" actually do? Thank you for your help !

Comment: | (vertical bar) in C is logical OR. That means a bit will be set to "1" if it is "1" in either A or B. & (ampersand) in C is logical AND. The bit will only be set if that bit is "1' in both A and B. |= and &= perform the operation in place so A |= B is equivalent to A = A | B